# How to add MailChimp subscribe widget to a page? (not a sidebar widget)

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I am trying to create a dedicated landing page where the only thing there will be the sign-up form to join my mailing list.

Is there a way to do that?

I already have MailChimp widget on the sidebar of my blog posts, but this is slightly different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailchimp forms can also be embedded in your page

http://mailchimp.com/features/custom-forms/